# What's the difference between "puberty" and "adolescence"?

Tags: differences, nouns

The two words *puberty* and *adolescence* seem to be referring to one thing; what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In short: *puberty* is a period of physical transition, *adolescence* is about a psychological and social transition.

---

*Puberty* is the process of physical changes by which *adolescents* reach sexual maturity, i.e. become capable of reproduction. *Puberty* refers to the bodily changes, while *adolescence* is the period of psychological and social transition between childhood and adulthood. (sources: [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puberty)[pedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolescence) and *New Oxford American Dictionary*).

In nonspecialized discussion and writing, the meanings tend to get blurred, and *puberty* can be used to refer to the period during which the changes happen, getting a meaning closer to *adolescence*. *Adolescence* still encompasses a typically larger period of time, however: *puberty* is over when the young individual's body has fully transformed, while it takes some more time for him or her to be recognized as an adult. Criteria for the latter are somewhat arbitrary, the typical example being “having reached the age of majority or being emancipated” (the age of majority depending on the country of residence). Some people even talk of 20-something adolescents to refer to people who have not yet reached an autonomous state of living, while being of full legal age.

---

As a side note, *adolescence* has a related noun (*adolescent*) and adjective (also *adolescent*), while *puberty* has a related noun (*pubescent*) and three adjectives (*pubescent*, *pubertal*, and sometimes *puberal*).  It also has a synonym, "pubescence."

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that puberty (as in sexual maturation) can happen during childhood (precocious puberty) or at the end of adolescence (late puberty).

Comment: @nico: I'm not an expert in the field, but it seems that childhood medically ends with the onset of puberty, doesn't it?

Comment: @F'x: I guess the definitions are sometimes a bit *loose*, even in scientific contexts. For sure I would not call a 6 year old an adolescent, even if he/she is going through precocious puberty. As you said, *adolescence* is more a "psychological" matter and *puberty* is more "physical". In the majority of cases, the periods largely overlap, so there is normally no issue.

Comment: Also worth noting is the related concept of "teenagerhood", which apparently only exists in English (and maybe other Germanic languages) - French, for example, has no such distinction.

Comment: You missed an adjective: *pubic*.

Comment: @fredley: *pubic* is from the same Latin root, but is not related directly meaning to *puberty*. Other words with the same root also include *pubes* and *pubis*.

Answer (score 7):

Puberty

- Refers to a biological process
- Can begin and end independent of adolescence
- May be described in terms of concrete physiological terms

Adolescence

- Refers to a period of time, usually teenage years though not always
- Will (practically) always overlap puberty while remaining distinct
- Described mostly in abstract psychological & sociological terms

Puberty *does* have some influence over mental maturity and development mainly through hormonal changes while adolescence generally speaks of personality and social maturity. It is common to notice that during adolescence there are certain physical changes such as a tendency to increase in height and changes in body shape but these are usually puberty's overlap or a continuation of the normal growth process.

Of these, I believe the main difference to be that puberty is a concrete biological processes where adolescence is an abstract social concept and the two do not always coincide in their entirety.

Answer (score 5):

As reported by the *Collins English Dictionary*, *puberty* is "the period at the beginning of adolescence when the sex glands become functional and the secondary sexual characteristics emerge;" *adolescence* means "the period in human development that occurs between the beginning of puberty and adulthood."
*Puberty* is then used when referring to physical changes, and *adolescence* when referring to social and psychological changes.